# Inverse of invertible sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be sheaf on scheme $X$ such that it's locally is $\mathcal{O}$ i want to prove that $$\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{O})\otimes \mathcal{L} \simeq \mathcal{O}$$ it's quite obvious intuitively or if we considering line bundles. Can someone explain it in details?

Comment: You probably want to use some kind of "curly Hom". Anyway, can you get started by writing down a morphism from the left to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a natural map $\mathscr{Hom}(\mathscr L, \mathscr O) \otimes \mathscr L \to \mathscr O$ given by $\varphi \otimes g \mapsto \varphi(f)$. Indeed, cover $X$ by affines such that the formula makes sense, and note that the same formula holds on the intersections, so we have a well-defined global map.

Now we can consider the stalks of these two sheaves at a closed point $P \in X$. But since $\mathscr L$ is locally free, $\mathscr L_P \simeq \mathscr O_P$, so we get $\mathscr{Hom}(\mathscr O_P, \mathscr O_P) \otimes \mathscr O_P \to \mathscr O_P$, which is an isomorphism.

Hence the map is locally an isomorphism, hence it is an isomorphism.

Comment: You should explain why the stalk of _this_ sheaf hom is what you say it is.

Comment: See Lemma 17.22.4 from Stacks Project for the proof that the stalk of hom is the hom of the stalk: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01CP
This argument is for the general case $\hom(\mathcal F,\mathcal G)$, with $\mathcal F$ finitely presented, over a locally ringed space. Maybe an easier argument can be given in the invertible case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an argument that avoids stalks (but I will use a basic results on quasi-coherent sheaves). I write a lot, but nothing surprising happens. We first show the following

**Lemma.** Let $\mathcal L$ be an invertible sheaf on a scheme $(X,\mathcal O_X)$. Then $\hom(\mathcal L,\mathcal O_X)$ is invertible.

*Proof.* Let $p\in X$ and choose an open affine $U\subset X$ that contains $p$ such that $\mathcal L\vert_U\cong\mathcal O_U$. Then
$$
\hom_{\mathcal O_U}(\mathcal L\vert_U,\mathcal O_U)\cong\hom_{\mathcal O_U}(\mathcal O_U,\mathcal O_U).
$$
We define a canonical map
$$
\phi:\hom_{\mathcal O_U} (O_U,\mathcal O_U)\to\mathcal O_U
$$
described on opens $V\subset U$ by
$$
\phi_V:\hom_{\mathcal O_V}(\mathcal O_V,\mathcal O_V)\to\mathcal O_X(V),(\sigma:\mathcal O_V\to\mathcal O_V)\mapsto \sigma_V(1).
$$
It's straightforward to verify that $\phi$ is a map of sheaves. We argue that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. To this end, note that for any open affine $V\subset U$, we have $\mathcal O_V\cong\widetilde{\mathcal O_X(V)}$ (here the tilde stands for the tilde-construction, see section 5.1.2 in Liu's Algebraic Geometry) since $\mathcal O_X$ is quasi-coherent (see e.g. Theorem 5.1.6 in Liu), and therefore
$$
\hom_{\mathcal O_U}(\mathcal O_U,\mathcal O_U)\cong\hom_{\mathcal O_X(U)}(\mathcal O_X(U),\mathcal O_X(U)),
$$
by Exercise 5.1.5 (b) in Liu (similar statements can also be found in Stacks Project: see [Section 1.17.10 Quasi-Coherent Modules](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BD)).
Since $\phi_V$ is the composition
$$
\hom_{\mathcal O_V}(\mathcal O_V,\mathcal O_V)\cong\hom_{\mathcal O_X(V)}(\mathcal O_X(V),\mathcal O_X(V))\cong\mathcal O_X(V)
$$
it follows that $\phi_V$, and therefore $\phi$ is an isomorphism. This concludes the proof of the lemma.

**Proof of: $\hom(\mathcal L,\mathcal O_X)\cong\mathcal O_X$**

We now show that the canonical map
$$
\hom(\mathcal L,\mathcal O_X)\otimes\mathcal O_X\to\mathcal O_X
$$
is an isomorphism. It suffices to do this locally. So let $U\subset X$ be an open such that we have an isomorphism $\psi:\mathcal L\vert_U\cong\mathcal O_U$. We have canonical maps which yield
$$
\mathcal O_U\cong \mathcal O_U\otimes\mathcal O_U\cong\hom(\mathcal O_U,\mathcal O_U)\otimes\mathcal O_U\cong \hom(\mathcal L\vert_U,\mathcal O_U)\otimes\mathcal L\vert_U\to\mathcal O_U,
$$
given by
$$
\sigma\mapsto 1\otimes\sigma\mapsto 1\otimes\sigma\mapsto \psi\otimes \psi^{-1}(\sigma)\mapsto \sigma.
$$
Note that the second map is an isomorphism by the lemma. The first and third map are also clearly isomorphisms. Since the composition is an isomorphism (it's the identity map), it follows that
$$
\hom(\mathcal L\vert_U,\mathcal O_U)\otimes\mathcal L\vert_U\to\mathcal O_U
$$
is an isomorphism.